# Running google cloud endpoints without App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm running **Google Cloud Endpoints** on **Google App Engine** ([python endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/) and soon [go endpoints](https://github.com/crhym3/go-endpoints) too)

Does it make sense to use Google Cloud endpoints without app engine e.g. on a personal server or such? Is it possible? What would be involved? (I'm thinking app engine does some magic around endpoints & api explorers etc.. which might need re implementing?)

Answer (score 1):

This may help and it's open source:
http://www.appscale.com/

And I found the site from here: https://cloud.google.com/partners/technology-partners/app-engine/

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to use endpoints on appscale. (couldn't find any examples of it).
Also I don't need all the other things appscale comes with. I just want to build a discovery document, do some auth, send and receive some json.